# Launch server via outlook

Tags: html, outlook, power-automate

I have a created an Html body for a mail and I am sending the mail via Power Automate Flow.
In the html if I just give the link like `href='C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe'` then it is opening the the remote desktop application but if I try to pass the argument as well like `href='C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe -v:<Server name>'`, it is giving me error saying `Could find 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe -v:<Server name>'`

Does anyone know if there is a way to do so via html mail or any other way?

Comment: I would expect any sane email client to forbid this sort of thing.

Answer (score -2):

In HTML you can pass links but the links aren't necessarily intended to be able to run files like the way you are looking for. You are looking for a way to run an executable with parameters which is a major security risk and so technically there really isn't a documented way to do that. But I recommend you check this out [HTML hyperlink to call exe with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994595/html-hyperlink-to-call-exe-with-parameters)